# GeoJson c# example parse countries in the world and generate Geojson for each country

Tags: c#, json, geojson

Looking for an example of how to parse / deserialize  Geojson files using geojson.net. for some reason there are no examples of how to use the geojson.net package.

I would like to use this on my site with the google maps api. currently I use polygon shapes but want to move towards using geojson objects for the layers as this seems to be a better format.

using c# I would like to serialize Geojson, select specific country borders and generate a new geojson file that can be references and added to google maps as a layer.

to test this I created a colsole app to try to deserilaize the GeoJson, this does not work (please could you give me some direction on the correct way to deserialize Geojson ?)

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Jsonstring = File.ReadAllText("c:/worldborders.json");
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<GeoJsonProperties> ns = (List<GeoJsonProperties>)ser.Deserialize(Jsonstring, typeof(List<GeoJsonProperties>));

?ns is Empty?


    }
```

I created a class for the geojson file using the online generator  http://json2csharp.com/ (I had thought that GeoJson.net would include the class as its a standard) ,      GeoJsonProperties,

```
 public class GeoJsonProperties
{
    public int scalerank { get; set; }
    public string featurecla { get; set; }
    public double labelrank { get; set; }
    public string sovereignt { get; set; }
    public string sov_a3 { get; set; }
    public double adm0_dif { get; set; }
    public double level { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string admin { get; set; }
    public string adm0_a3 { get; set; }
    public double geou_dif { get; set; }
    public string geounit { get; set; }
    public string gu_a3 { get; set; }
    public double su_dif { get; set; }
    public string subunit { get; set; }
    public string su_a3 { get; set; }
    public double brk_diff { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string name_long { get; set; }
    public string brk_a3 { get; set; }
    public string brk_name { get; set; }
    public object brk_group { get; set; }
    public string abbrev { get; set; }
    public string postal { get; set; }
    public string formal_en { get; set; }
    public string formal_fr { get; set; }
    public string note_adm0 { get; set; }
    public string note_brk { get; set; }
    public string name_sort { get; set; }
    public string name_alt { get; set; }
    public double mapcolor7 { get; set; }
    public double mapcolor8 { get; set; }
    public double mapcolor9 { get; set; }
    public double mapcolor13 { get; set; }
    public double pop_est { get; set; }
    public double gdp_md_est { get; set; }
    public double pop_year { get; set; }
    public double lastcensus { get; set; }
    public double gdp_year { get; set; }
    public string economy { get; set; }
    public string income_grp { get; set; }
    public double wikipedia { get; set; }
    public object fips_10 { get; set; }
    public string iso_a2 { get; set; }
    public string iso_a3 { get; set; }
    public string iso_n3 { get; set; }
    public string un_a3 { get; set; }
    public string wb_a2 { get; set; }
    public string wb_a3 { get; set; }
    public double woe_id { get; set; }
    public string adm0_a3_is { get; set; }
    public string adm0_a3_us { get; set; }
    public double adm0_a3_un { get; set; }
    public double adm0_a3_wb { get; set; }
    public string continent { get; set; }
    public string region_un { get; set; }
    public string subregion { get; set; }
    public string region_wb { get; set; }
    public double name_len { get; set; }
    public double long_len { get; set; }
    public double abbrev_len { get; set; }
    public double tiny { get; set; }
    public double homepart { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<List<List<object>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public GeoJsonProperties  properties { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> features { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoJSON.Net works with Newtonsoft.Json. you can deserialize the same way you would using that library.

```
var geoJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Point>(json);
```

Answer (score 4):

For deserializing a  FeatureCollection object (like the one you mention in the question) using the GeoJSON.Net library use the following code :

```
var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeatureCollection>(json);
```