# Get the properties of Coordinates points in json/geojson file using C#/ newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, geometry, geojson

1- I uploaded a geojson file and wanted to do some queries to fetch the data based on the coordinate points (longitude and latitude). I would like to insert the coordinates to get the places such as (Park or Street). how can I search for the coordinate points if it exists in the array and then bring back the NAME of these points?

Here is the geojson/json file

```
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "Places",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -0.123, 9.123 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "id" : "9",
                "Name" : "Park",
},
{
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -0.321, 9.321 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "id" : "10",
                "Name" : "Street",
}
]
{
```

Classes and main programm

````
        {

            public string type { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }  
            public Feature[] features { get; set; }

        }

        public class Feature
        {
            public string type { get; set; }

            public Geometry geometry { get; set; }

            public Properties properties { get; set; }
        }
        public class Properties
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string Name{ get; set; }
        }

        public class Geometry
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }


        }
    } ```

          static void Main(string[] args)
        {
{{ string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\places.geojson");
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(json);

            // Here I could get the lists of coordinates and the names
            for (int i = 0; i < result.features.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Coordinates:" + result.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0] + ","
                    + result.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1] + " Name:" + "    " +
                    result.features[i].properties.Name);


                //I want to insert manualy the coordinate point to get the NAME
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Longitude ");
            double lon = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
} ```
````

Comment: you just described a task, not not where specifically you need our help. So what exactly is your problem with the above code? Does it work? Does it produce unexecpected results? If so what are the results you expect and wehat do you get instead?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057828/geojson-c-sharp-example-parse-countries-in-the-world-and-generate-geojson-for-ea

Comment: Thanks @himBromBeere .. I've edited the questions. basically, I'm querying about extracting the properties from the array by making a condition so I need a hint about how can I do this. the issue is that I'm using an array inside an array.

Comment: I query my geojson using LINQ, after deser'ing it in a similar way to how you do here. Something like `result.Features.Where(f => f.Geometry.Coordinates[0] is > 1 and < 2))`